Intercepting test failures to provide additional context
TL;DR: Is there any known hack to capture and/or print additional context when a Golang test fails? (using standard library testing)
Example:
func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
  ...
  ...
  if ... {
    t.Fatalf("Something went wrong!")
  }

I would like to attach some generic function to be invoked before the test returns, e.g. debug.PrintStack()
I am working on a large codebase with hundreds of tests.

Moving to a different testing library is not an option
Modifying each test is not an option (e.g. add defer)
I'd really like to avoid re-implementing go test logic...
(the actual use case is not debug.PrintStack() -- I want to notify some other system of the test failure)

I can see from testing documentation and code that this is not supported.
However I also know if one is determined enough, this is possible, and I am hoping someone can point to some clever hack I can take inspiration from.

Ahem... It is called Fatalf for a reason: https://pkg.go.dev/testing#T.Fatalf. And if you want to notify a system... Why don't you do it? if err != nil { notifySystem() } Also, you can simply implement your own test runner. However, the simplest solution is is to use a CI system, most of which basically all do something in the area of go test -v ./... || notifyUserByVariousMeansThatSomethingWentWrongAndDebuggingIsNeeded.sh

Thank you for your comment. The point is not unhelpful Fatalf messages, the code I provided was just an example. The point is to stop the system and capture arbitrary additional data & state. My question already answers your two "why don't you..." suggestions. I know I'm asking for something unorthodox here (a way to extend testing in a way that it was not designed to). Wrapping with a script as you suggest is what I am in fact doing now, using -json. Tho doing it in-process could provide useful additional context.

It sounds to me like you want to have the cake and eat it. When a test fails and the problem isn't obvious, using a debugger to get the context you need makes a whole lot more sense than to create a LOT of noise. And yes, as written: you can implement your own test runner utilizing testing. This way, you can create a snapshot of your environment with all the bells and whistles you want, run your test, evaluate (*T).Failed() and react however you want to. Will this help? I doubt it very much, since you need to access the code anyway.

It is not uncommon for software to provide hooks for extensions. Other testing libraries do, the testing library does not, which is understandable for a standard library, to keep it clean and simple. I don't need a debugger, I am not debugging failing tests, I am gathering data at scale, I want an injection point to capture data. I already came up with a terrible hack to do what the question asks for via reflection and method substitution. I was hoping for someone to provide a more elegant hack. Seems way out of your wheelhouse so let's stop wasting time.

So as repeatedly said: Write yourself a custom testrunner. Have a look at https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/suite for example. You can add all the bells and whistles you want, and it is not even complicated. And between you and me: Becoming passive-aggressive when you get answers that tell you something you do not like will not get you far.
